# RSpec: Swap methods? e.g. stub one method with another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Let's say I have a nested scope call on a model.

```
# model
scope :one, -> { ... }
scope :two, -> { ... }
scope :three, -> { ... }

def self.narrow_set_of_records
  one.two.three
end
```

To simplify testing, I would like to be able to have `two` return `all` instead of perform its usual scope, returning all of the results from `one`. Is there a way to do this with RSpec? e.g.

```
# This doesn't seem to be working
allow(Model).to receive(:two).and_return(:all)
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to actually mock a [message chain](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains).

something like this ought to work:

```
allow(Model).to receive_message_chain(:one, :two) {Model.all}
```

Comment: then have it return `Model.one` instead of `Model.all`

Comment: I see that. I could also just mock `two` to return `Model.one`. That would work, but that's order dependent. If the order were changed, my tests would be inaccurate.

Comment: see the warning in that link i posted. It talks about how tests like this (and consequently code like this) leads to brittle testing behavior for the precise reason you mention.

Comment: That warning doesn't apply to these scopes. Chained scopes do not violate the Law of Demeter, provided they are returning collections of that class. Good scopes will return the same collection when changed, independent of order.